# Best place to store custom objects so all activities can see them

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, custom-object

I am an iOS developer who is trying to learn Android and I would like to make sure that I am following best practices.

I have custom objects that need to be accessible by 1 -> m activities and they need to be saved when the application closes. Currently I am using SharedPreferences, code below, to save them but I am not sure if it is the best route. Should I be using a singleton? Is there a better way?

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(userProfile);
prefsEditor.putString("UserProfile", json);
prefsEditor.commit();

gson = new Gson();
json = mPrefs.getString("UserProfile", "");
UserProfileObject outObject = gson.fromJson(json, UserProfileObject.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A singleton won't be saved when the application exits.  Really your options are:

*SharedPreferences.  Good for a small number of key/value pairs

*Database.  Good for relational data

*File on disk, in whatever format you prefer.  Good for any amount of data, but you may need to write a custom parser.

Storing json in a shared preference is a bit weird.  Its not horrible so long as you aren't storing a lot of keys in there, but it makes it seem like you didn't know how to write a file.

Comment: I am googling my way through learning android development I can figure out how to write a file. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Gabe has provided a good answer. I am adding my 2 cents to it

I personally do not like to save serialised data in SharedPreferences. Instead I would use local db storage such as SQLite or Realm to store it. The reason being serialisation/deserialisation involves marshalling/unmarshalling objects using reflection which could potentially hit performance in a negative way.

In short, Use local db for storing complex / relational data and SharedPreferences for storing simple data

Answer (score 0):

I think if your `UserProfileObject` can be easily constructed from Json and it doesn't contain any sensitive data (i.e. password), might be fine just having it in `SharedPreferences` (just save the json string like what you are doing).

Using a singleton SessionManager / ProfileManager class with that should be sufficient enough. Even though it might be used by 1 -> m activities, it only hits the `SharedPreferences` once using the singleton. Just make sure you keep the copy of the data in the singleton and in `SharedPreferences` in sync when there are changes. Or just dump the singleton all together and hit the `SharedPreferences` every time you need it (less worries about keeping copies in sync), don't think your use case will hammer it that much.